# Curve fitting with a polar input variable

Tags: predictive-models, curve-fitting, circular-statistics

Imagine we have a set of data, with two variables, the first of which can be represented in polar co-ordinates (for example hour or day, or day of week). The second variable is a real valued and has some relationship with the first. The data might look something like the following:

[image]

I would like to fit a closed curve to this data, which maximises the likelihood of the data for the purpose of making predictions. I only have a single cycle of data, so I cannot do extract seasonal or trends through decomposition . What methods are recommended?

(p.s. I'm using R)

Comment: For fitting likelihoods, there's nothing special about this problem.  Nothing differs in the least from fitting curves in Cartesian coordinates: as always, you write down the likelihood function and find its maxima.  What, then, are you trying to ask?

Comment: I suppose there is an implicit expectation that since I want the curve to be closed, that I will need to use some other method to generate the curve. I only have experience fitting polynomials. Perhaps my question is, "what is a good basis function for this kind or problem?"...

Comment: I was wondering whether that's where you were headed.  If you want an answer that has a good chance of being appropriate for your data, then you ought to describe what your data mean and your assumptions about them.  Otherwise, you're not really asking about maximum likelihood: your question seems to reduce to "what are ways to fit a continuous function to circular data?"  Would that be a correct interpretation?  If that's the case, check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68403/smooth-a-circular-periodic-time-series/68504#68504.