# Zero inflated model with prediction

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, bootstrap, zero-inflation

I am analyzing host seeking behavior (called questing) of ticks from two populations (Lab and field collected). I have ~20 percent zeros in my dataset. I had 20 ticks per enclosure (where 0 is no ticks questing and up to 20 ticks can quest, can be expressed as a proportion).

For variables I also have time of day, tree stand, collection method, and weather.

I want to find if there is a way to predict if a higher proportion of ticks will quest by each of these variables. (i.e are ticks more likely to quest during the night, a specific tree stand, or weather event and is collection method significant for each of these?

I'm a little lost on how to model this, however I was very interested and tried to utilize this method [I have zero inflated data, with discrete variables. Is it possible to use zero inflated poisson model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594209/i-have-zero-inflated-data-with-discrete-variables-is-it-possible-to-use-zero-i) to graph the probability of questing with time of day on the x axis based on stand and weather. Thanks @EdM for helping!

| time | time of day | stand | weather | collection | Total_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05:24 | morning | pine | rain | lab | 3 |
| 14:12 | afternoon | oak | clear | field | 0 |
| 20:45 | evening | birch | cloudy | lab | 5 |
| 00:30 | night | ash | rain | field | 1 |

---

[Raw Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L35ZhR5EE7Ei6VYTqpgjFsPDttD6isLivJvugioeBVw/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Link to the data: [RAW DATA](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L35ZhR5EE7Ei6VYTqpgjFsPDttD6isLivJvugioeBVw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi Elizabeth. Welcome to CV. Please make sure you add any substantial info to your question's body rather than leave as a comment. Best wishes.